# Node.js: How to create paid node modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, module, node-modules

How to sell node modules?

I need to publish my CMS plugins to NPM and allow users to install them, so some of them could be paid.

How do i do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Contrary to some of the answers here, not everything on npm is open-source or publicly available to anyone - npm supports organizations, scoped packages, private modules and private scoped packages with restricted access. Even if it didn't, you can still host a private npm registry (see below) or host a module on GitHub or GitLab or any other git server, where you also can have private repositories with restricted access granted to your customers.

You can create a private npm module:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/intro

You can add access to such modules to your customers:

> If you want to give access to someone, they need to be subscribed to private modules as well. Once they are, you can give them read or read-write access.
>
> You can control access to the package on the access page. To get to the page, click on the Collaborators link or the plus button.

Or you can host your own private npm registry:

- http://thejackalofjavascript.com/maintaining-a-private-npm-registry/

And you can host your modules on GitHub or GitLab or any other git server instead of npm.

Comment: Is there any free way?

Comment: @HasanBayat A free way would be hosting a private registry with a tool like [sinopia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia) or using a private repository on [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) that you can have for free.

Comment: is sinopia needs server?

Comment: Do you mean gitlab trial enterprise?

Comment: How do i implement it on gitlab?

Comment: @HasanBayat Yes, sinopia needs a server that you host it on. With GitLab I don't mean any trial or enterprise, just a normal account on [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com/). When you [create a new project](https://gitlab.com/projects/new) there's an option to make it Private. Then you can add users who have access to it - or you can [create a group](https://gitlab.com/groups/new) and then create a private project as that group and make it accessible to members of that group.

Comment: Thanks. But i'm going to host my own website.

Comment: Webmaster's account has been suspended: http://thejackalofjavascript.com/maintaining-a-private-npm-registry/

Comment: Github now also offers free private repositories ─ and organizations.

Answer (score 4):

Adding on to the previous answers, the best available approaches now is to create a private npm package and  share it over any market place.

Available options are

1. [PRIV Js](https://privjs.com/)

   - Its an javascript marketplace where you can sell your JS packages or purchase from others.
   - Provides its own interface to create private packages so you don't need to have your own server.
   - It lets you control the pricing and track downloads or grant special access as required.
   - Supports scoped packages as well.
2. [Base Tools](https://basetools.io/)

   - Helps to create a paywall for your npm package
   - Provides github integration to your private repositories.
3. [Github sponsor only repos](https://github.blog/2022-02-02-new-sponsors-only-repositories-custom-amounts-and-more/)

   - Github has recently enabled sponsor only repositories
   - This enables you to give access to only those who are willing to sponsor to your project.
4. [Gumroad](https://gumroad.com/)

   - Its an marketplace to sell anything

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but a lot has happened in the past years.

One solution you can use nowadays is [basetools.io](https://basetools.io) for selling access to your npm packages. It takes care of invoicing, billing and managing access to your packages.

Full disclosure: I am the founder of basetools.