# how to have multiple deploys from a node app

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I would like to know what is the best approach in create several deploys from a big code base. The idea is to **divide the big API into microservices** (each one in it's own server/vm),

The first idea: I could simply create a folder **with only the available routes** for that microservice, but still using the "common" codebase...

I currently end up with this, and it's a running API in production (with staging environment in **heroku** with their pipeline):

[image]

and I was thinking that I could have something like:

[image]

can anyone point me to a good reference on ... where to start? how can I push multiple version of the same base code to a server?

for more detail on the used technologies, I'm using:

- **mocha** and **chai** for tests
- **sequelize** for mariaDb modeling and access
- **restify** for server engine

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070456/how-to-have-multiple-deploys-from-a-node-app/44071407#44071407) below help? Any comments?

Comment: @esp not really ... still waiting for a better answer :)

Answer (score 1):

When you divide the API into microservices, you have few options:

1. Make completely separate repos for all of them with some code duplication
2. Make completely separate repos but sharing common code as Node modules
3. Make one repo with multiple microservices, each as its own Node module
4. Make one repo with one big codebase and build multiple modules with needed parts from that
5. I'm sure you can do it in even more ways

Having a mismatch of the number of Node modules and code repos will cause some troubles but it may have some benefits in certain cases.

Having a 1-to-1 mapping of repos and modules will be easier to work with with some cases, like the ability to add private GitHub repos directy to dependencies in package.json.

If you want to factor out some common functionality then you can do it in several ways:

1. The npm supports organizations, scoped packages, private modules and private scoped packages with restricted access.
2. You can host a private npm registry
3. You can host a module on GitHub or GitLab or any other git server

For more info see:

- [Node.js: How to create paid node modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931691/node-js-how-to-create-paid-node-modules/42931785#42931785)

There are some nice frameworks that can help you with splitting your code base into microservices, like Seneca:

- http://senecajs.org/

Or to a certain extent with Serverless if you're using AWS Lambda, Microsoft Azure, IBM OpenWhisk or Google Cloud Platform:

- https://serverless.com/